# Hidden Values using class

Tags: python, pandas

I do not get all values.
Here is what the original table looks like, here you can see at position Day4 and T there is an extra span class"ntee" which represents number 4
[image: Here is what the original table looks like, here you can see at position Day4 and T there is an extra span class"ntee" which represents number 4]
Here is how I get it into pandas
[image: Here is how I get it into pandas]

Is there a way to get all data?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 500)
import time
import requests

page = requests.get("https://en.tutiempo.net/climate/01-2021/ws-66320.html/")
page

soup = bs(page.content)
soup

myTable=soup.find('table',{'class':"medias mensuales numspan"})
myTable

row_headers=[]
for x in myTable.find_all("tr"):
    for y in x.find_all("th"):
        row_headers.append(y.text)
row_headers

table_values= []
for x in myTable.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    td_tags = x.find_all("td")
    td_values= [y.text for y in td_tags]
    table_values.append(td_values)
table_values

pd.DataFrame(table_values[:-2],columns=row_headers[:-1])
```

Comment: without the data it's hard to pinpoint. Maybe share with us the contents of `row_headers` before the dataframe constructor and figure out where the extra header is coming from

Comment: the url of the website is in : https://en.tutiempo.net/climate/01-2021/ws-66320.html

Comment: The error message likely means that there are 16 columns supplied in `row_headers`, but only 15 columns in `table_values` (or the other way around, not 100% sure). That is easy to check, by printing the values (given that this is a notebook, you've already done that; do compare the two outputs for their amount of columns). The solution is to double check the original table; it may be malformed, or simply a column left out.

Comment: this website is asking for money for free information, I thought of finding a way to obtain this data for free.

Comment: While off-topic: arguably, the website is asking for money for *providing* a way to retrieve otherwise free information; it could be that the free information is difficult to retrieve or parse. But that's besides the point of your question anyway.

Comment: Given `for x in myTable.find_all("tr"): for y in x.find_all("th"):`: have you considered that there may be more `th` elements in other rows than just the first one? `th` elements can also be used on each row, similar to an index in Pandas. If the table is properly formatted, you should use the `thead` element instead.

Comment: There are 15 values and 16 headers. I do not need the last header from the list, could you tell me how to not include the last element from the row_header array?

Comment: may be - `df = pd.read_html('https://en.tutiempo.net/climate/01-2021/ws-66320.html/', attrs={'class': "medias mensuales numspan"})[0]`

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(table_values,columns=row_headers[:-1])`

Comment: I changed the question, they made it a bit more tricky to scrap this webpage. Can anyone help me gather all info

Answer (score 1):

I will just explain the logic of work with a simple example. When you get the page, in the **style** tag, the page generates values ​​corresponding to the class values ​​of the **span** tag.

```
<style>.tablancpy{-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;}.numspan span.ntjk::after{content:"1";color:black;}.numspan span.ntrs::after{content:"2";color:black;}.numspan span.ntza::after{content:"3";color:black;}.numspan span.ntaa::after{content:"4";color:black;}.numspan span.ntbz::after{content:"5";color:black;}.numspan span.ntgy::after{content:"6";color:black;}.numspan span.ntox::after{content:"7";color:black;}.numspan span.ntqr::after{content:"8";color:black;}.numspan span.ntnt::after{content:"9";color:black;}.numspan span.ntbc::after{content:"0";color:black;}.numspan span.ntvr::after{content:".";color:black;}.numspan span.ntzz::after{content:"-";color:black;}</style>
```

If we look at the table, where there is no value, we see this

```
<td><span class="ntaa"></span><span class="ntvr"></span><span class="ntbz"></span></td>
```

Further, the logic is simple if there is no text in the **td** tag. We just take the class names of the **span** tag and compare them with the data obtained. Examlpe:

```
response = requests.get('https://en.tutiempo.net/climate/12-2021/ws-66320.html')
matches = re.findall(r'\.\w{4}::', response.text)
foo = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '.', '-']
spans = dict(zip([x[1:-2] for x in matches], foo))
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
for tr in soup.find('table', class_='medias mensuales numspan').find_all('tr')[3:5]:
    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
        if td.get_text():
            print(td.get_text())
        else:
            span_classes = [x.get('class')[0] for x in td.find_all('span')]
            print(span_classes, ''.join([spans[x] for x in span_classes]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
3
0
2.5
-3.7
1017
-
1.02
-
8.3
24.1
-
 
4
['ntee', 'ntkk', 'ntgo'] 4.5
['ntpo', 'ntkk', 'ntef'] 7.3
['ntfg', 'ntkk', 'ntee'] 0.4
['ntno', 'ntfg', 'ntfg', 'ntdr', 'ntkk', 'ntee'] 1006.4
['ntjg', 'ntvw'] 92
['ntno', 'ntpo', 'ntkk', 'ntgo', 'ntef'] 17.53
['ntjj'] -
['ntno', 'ntjg', 'ntkk', 'ntee'] 19.4
['ntvw', 'ntjg', 'ntkk', 'ntee'] 29.4
['ntjj'] -
```

UPDATE:

```
page = requests.get("https://en.tutiempo.net/climate/01-2021/ws-66320.html/")
soup = bs(page.text, 'lxml')
matches = re.findall(r'\.\w{4}::', page.text)
foo = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '.', '-']
spans = dict(zip([x[1:-2] for x in matches], foo))
myTable = soup.find('table', {'class': "medias mensuales numspan"})
row_headers = []
for x in myTable.find_all("tr"):
    for y in x.find_all("th"):
        row_headers.append(y.text)
table_values = []
for x in myTable.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    td_values = []
    for td in x.find_all('td'):
        if td.get_text():
            td_values.append(td.get_text())
        else:
            td_values.append(''.join([spans[y] for y in [y.get('class')[0] for y in td.find_all('span')]]))
    table_values.append(td_values)

df = pd.DataFrame(table_values[:-2], columns=row_headers[:-1])
print(df)
```

Comment: when I try the code provided by you I get an error: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_23756/1700714560.py in <module>
      6 
      7 response = requests.get('https://en.tutiempo.net/climate/12-2021/ws-66320.html')
----> 8 matches = re.findall(r'\.\w{4}::', response.text)
      9 foo = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '0', '.', '-']
     10 spans = dict(zip([x[1:-2] for x in matches], foo))

NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: I understand the last part, it is very helpful, but I do not understand the spans array.

Comment: @StetcoOana you combine the resulting classes from matches with array foo into a dictionary, you can see the function [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) . In result spans dict looks like - `{'nthi': '1', 'ntpq': '2', 'ntxy': '3', 'ntgg': '4', 'ntaz': '5', 'ntyy': '6', 'ntxo': '7', 'ntre': '8', 'ntll': '9', 'ntab': '0', 'ntux': '.', 'ntkf': '-'}` 
and you can get values ​​by key - `spans['nthi']` in this case value will be 1

Comment: I understand now. All worked when I wanted to print, but if I want to create the dataFrame it gives me the following error : ValueError: Shape of passed values is (478, 1), indices imply (478, 15)

Comment: pd.DataFrame(table_values[:-2],columns=row_headers[:-1]) this line makes the error.

Comment: @StetcoOana i add a little to ure code, check the updated post